# gCloud / GCE Disk Size warning - is it meaningful?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcloud-cli

When I create a boot disk with gCloud less than 200GB in size, I see this error:

```
WARNING: You have selected a disk size of under [200GB]. This may result in poor I/O performance. For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#pdperformance.
```

I don't, however, see the details about this 200GB size which it alludes to being at somewhere on the page at that url.

Should I care about this warning at all? I wonder is it is more of a ploy for them to make more money trying to encourage you to lease more space?

Note: I'm using a standard disk, not a solid state.  My disk access performance which is of any concern is via MySQL with very small read / writes 99% of the time, and occasionally blobs in the range of say 1 to 100 MBs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the documentation has shifted around a little, and the warning is out of date.

There is a section of the [Block Storage page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdperformance) that explains the relationship between persistent disk size and performance.

We'll fix the URL in gcloud.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Zachary.  Could you help to understand some of what that says?  Based on my described use, should I be concerned about the size to performance relationship?

Comment: I would say that the only way to know for your use case is to benchmark–if you reach a point where disk access is a bottleneck, select a larger disk and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like this message is still around in the gcloud CLI - my version is 158.0.0

Comment: I see the new URL in the current version of the CLI–note the difference between `/docs/disks` (new URL) and `/docs/disks/persistent-disks` (old URL). Looks like the anchor has shifted to just `#performance`, though.